# Inserting dummy values at the end of select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have got query which returns address and completed orders against each address for last week.
i need to insert three dummy values within the result set.

```
select  ADDRESS
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as Completed
from orders 
GROUP BY ADDRESS
order by ADDRESS
```

result

Address--------------Completed

address1----------------3

address2----------------3

address3----------------3

address4----------------3

all those values are coming from the database, but i want to insert three rows with hard coded values

Expected result

Address--------------Completed

address1----------------3

address2----------------3

address3----------------3

address4----------------3

dummy1------------------0

dummy2------------------0

dummy3------------------0

unsuccessful attempt

```
select  ADDRESS
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as Completed
from orders 

union all 
select
    'dummy1', 0
GROUP BY ADDRESS
order by ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  -

```
select  ADDRESS
,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
          Then 1
        Else 0 
        End) as Completed
from orders 
union all 
select
  'dummy1' AS Address, SUM(0) AS Completed 
GROUP BY ADDRESS
order by ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This - It May Help You Out:

[Adding a static value to the results of an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472115/adding-a-static-value-to-the-results-of-an-sql-query)

After the Union - Do

Select 'dummy1' as Address, 1 as Completed

Answer (score 0):

```
select ADDRESS
      ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
              Else 0 
              End) as Completed
from orders 
GROUP BY ADDRESS
UNION
select 'dummy1', 0
UNION
select 'dummy2', 0
UNION
select 'dummy3', 0
order by ADDRESS
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a dummy Table variable and then insert your selected records like this

```
DECLARE @ordertable (Address varchar(100), Completed int);

//Add your data
INSERT INTO @ordertable (Address, Completed) (
    select  ADDRESS
           ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
                Then 1
                Else 0 
                End) as Completed
    from orders 
    GROUP BY ADDRESS
    order by ADDRESS)

//Insert dummy data
INSERT INTO @ordertable (Address, Completed) VALUES(dummy1, 0)
INSERT INTO @ordertable (Address, Completed) VALUES(dummy2, 0)
INSERT INTO @ordertable (Address, Completed) VALUES(dummy3, 0)
```

Then just `SELECT * from @ordertable` and you're good to go!

Comment: your approach seems to work just amend your table creating code as below                                                                         DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      Address NVARCHAR(100) ,
      Completed TINYINT
    )